# How can I close and reopen viewController with button push?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on a notes app, and I would like the ability to close and reopen the already open New Note viewController by pushing a button on the view. When I do that now it opens a duplicate viewController on top of the already open viewController.

Is there a clean way I could close the viewController and reopen it with a button push? The New Note viewController is opened by a button push on a listView that is the root view of a navigationController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will refresh the current displayed VC

```
let vc  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notes")

self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
```

Comment: This almost works perfectly! The only issue is that the refreshed view does note have the back button to return to the root view anymore. Any ideas on how to get that guy back?